# Simple questions about outer in R

Tags: r, outer-join

I have a simple question about `outer()` in R.

```
x=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4),3,3)
d=ncol(x)
outer(1:d,0:(max(x)-1), function(j,k) sum(x[,j]>k))
```

The is the error I got from this code:

```
Error in outer(1:d, 0:(max(x) - 1), sum(x[,j]>k)) : 
  dims [product 21] do not match the length of object [1]
```

Could someone tell me why it is not working? and how to fix it by still using `outer()`?

Comment: the function you use in outer needs to be vectorized `f <- Vectorize(function(j, k) sum(x[,j]>k)); outer(1:d,0:(max(x)-1), f)`. read the details of `?outer`

Comment: Thanks rawr. It does work. I just wondering what the difference is between a vectorized function and not vectorized function?

Comment: if you think about it as mapping an input to an output, a vectorized function allows you to supply the entire range of inputs and get out the entire corresponding range of outputs. The alternative would be a function that takes one input and maps it to one output and then you repeat the process across the domain of inputs. There are examples in `?Vectorize` that you can play with which demonstrates this